# Webrtc support on native ios webview

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, wkwebview, webrtc-ios

I want to build an ios application, where I plan to have a native iOS webview in the app. Within the native webview, I want to be able to run a video call, using webrtc. Is this possible? Is webrtc supported by native iOS webviews?

Answer (score 1):

webview supports RTCPeerConnection but the state of getUserMedia is still unclear. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=752458 and the linked webkit bug.